# How to change navigation selection class according to page loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working in an iframe, i have to change navigation selection class according to page loaded in iframe. Currently when i click in menu then it is changing its class according to page. Now i have do the same thing from iframe.
For eg.
I have view more option for page in an iframe when i click on view more then it is going to its relative page, next thing is its parent navigation class must change according to that page.
Here is the image of my website page https://scontent.fixc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/16325676_1605456589512580_982961437_o.png?oh=fe6d78dd0feaf80afc6de416f2470992&oe=588B3496
Thanks in advance.